# How to test a login application for validation messages using formGroup or ngif element using protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I want to test whether my login application displays validation messages correctly. Without adding an id for the form can i check this using ngclass?

```
<form [formGroup]="authForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="authForm.get('email').hasError('required')">
                Email is required.
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate with the below code. If the alert is displayed in run time. Click inside the field and click on another feild without sending any values.

```
validationMessage = element(by.css('div.form-group>div');

validationMessage.getText().then((value:string) =>{
expect(value).toBe('Email is required.');
}
```

For info refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/locators

Hope it helps you

Comment: Can you help me to test validations when there are same div level 2 error messages? (ex: password is required and password do not match)

Comment: @SanjaniGunathilaka just make the `validationMessage` to `element.all(by.css('div.form-group>div')).get(1)`